# Python 3 remove duplicate weblinks with extra character rstrip

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Using Python 3. I am trying to pull all the unique links from a website and seem to have the code working except for a few links that have a / at the end.

For example: My program will include http://www.google.com & http://www.google.com/

I'd like to make sure my program removes that last character to ensure no duplicates will return. I have researched `rstrip()` but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/state-total.html').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

filename = "UniqueWebLinks.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "WebLinks\n"
f.write(headers)

all_links = soup.find_all('a')

url_set = set()

for link in all_links:
    web_links = link.get("href")
    ab_url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/state-total.html', web_links)
    print (ab_url)
    if ab_url and ab_url not in url_set:
        f.write(str(ab_url) + "\n")
        url_set.add(ab_url)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but census.gov has a bunch of APIs to get data from without scraping whatever is on their site. Perhaps what you're looking for isn't available in an API, but I'd definitely take a look there first: https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep it simple and be very explicit about how you're cleaning URLs. For example, strip the last character if it's a slash (`/`) or a hash (`#`) (if a URL ends with a hash, it's the same as it not ending with a hash). After glancing at the data, I'd also remove any blank URLs because that's probably not what you're looking for.

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/state-total.html'

all_links = soup.find_all('a')

def clean_links(tags, base_url):
    cleaned_links = set()
    for tag in tags:
        link = tag.get('href')
        if link is None:
            continue
        if link.endswith('/') or link.endswith('#'):
            link = link[-1]
        full_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link)
        cleaned_links.add(full_url)
    return cleaned_links

cleaned_links = clean_links(all_links, BASE_URL)

for link in cleaned_links:
    f.write(str(link) + '\n')
```